# Intent to view jpeg email attachments?

Tags: android, android-intent, attachment

I made an image viewer that opens an image using its file name. It also works when you click an image in a file manager using the URI, and I set it as my default viewer.

However, if I get an email with an image as attachment (I use K9 mail client) and I click on the image thumb, my viewer gets as file name just "VIEW". Makes sense, there's no file in the system. Of course, I can save the attachment and see it,  but I don't want to do this.

So, my question is: how can I make my viewer to get the attachment directly? Maybe this is the correct question: What does an email client return when you click the attachment "link" in the email?

*EDIT*

This is how I try to open an URI in my code:

```
        uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null)
            String file = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
```

and the funcion `getRealPathFromURI` is:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        String path = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
}
```

With this code, I get as path `content://com.fsck.k9.attachmentprovider/34fc2cc9-aa46-45e9-9e3f-2f27f0457249/1‌​/VIEW`, that is wrong of course. The correct one should be `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.fsck.k9/files/34fc2cc9-aa46-45e9-9e3f-2f27f0457249‌​.db_att/1`.

So the *correct* question is: why does the above `getRealPathFromURI()` function do not return the correct filepath?

Comment: if file not in device then how we show it..?? you must have to download it before show..

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha: Actually, the _data_ is in the device, inside the body of the email, as a mime type attachment. My question is: what does the email client do when you click on the "link" (thumbnail)? What does it send to the system? Thanks!

Comment: K9 is also downlod image.. From attachment after that they open and save... So when you click on link thunbnail they are downloading image first....

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha: I know that. What I am asking is what does K9 (or any other email app for that matter) do when I click in "Open"? Of course it saves the attachment (maybe in RAM), but what does it send as an Intent? I want to click in "Open" and see an image, but I see just black, because my app is not catching properly what K9 sends. If I click in "Save" I do see the image, but it is saved locally as a file and I don't want that because of annoyances (stupid Gallery app indexes the image when saved despite the .nomedia, for example). Please see what I tried in the edited question.

Comment: Ok, this is what K9 returns: `content://com.fsck.k9.attachmentprovider/34fc2cc9-aa46-45e9-9e3f-2f27f0457249/1/VIEW`. The actual file is located at `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.fsck.k9/files/34fc2cc9-aa46-45e9-9e3f-2f27f0457249.db_att/1`

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha: For some reason, the cursor is not returning the filepath, but instead the `content://`. Any idea why? I would think this is a K9 bug, but the Gallery process this correctly and show the image.

Comment: its happens only when after download image. application not perform Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED. thats why you did't get URI of that image...

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha: I still don't get it. This is the internal storage, and it's permanently mounted. Moreover, the file is already downloaded and present in the system, even before the click.